# Convert string into LocalDate Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to convert string value
this is my code like

```
val dateFirst = "20 Aug 2012"
val dateSecond = "12/16/2020 12:00:00 AM"

val dateFirstConverted = LocalDate.parse(dateFirst, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
val dateSecondConverted = LocalDate.parse(dateSecond, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)

println(dateFirstConverted)
println(dateSecondConverted)
```

then i get error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20 Aug 2012' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
    at App.TryKt.main(try.kt:11)
    at App.TryKt.main(try.kt)
```

can someone help me how to fix this ?

Comment: Do you know the pattern(s) a `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE` is able to parse? The `String`s you are trying to parse are not of those formats and the date in your example code even has a different format than the one from your exception trace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have problem because the format of the date is not supported, I invite you to read this article https://www.claudebueno.com/programmation/comment-gerer-la-date-et-lheure-avec-kotlin.htm but in your case if you want that the code runs, change the format of `date`, like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDate

fun main() {
    //example
    val current = LocalDateTime.now()
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE
    val formatted = current.format(formatter)
    println("Current Date is: $formatted")
    
    //your code
    val dates = /*"20 Aug 2012"*/ "20120820"
    val datess = LocalDate.parse(dates, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
    println(datess)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** ⇒ You are using the wrong pattern for parsing

1. Your date `String` is of the format `dd MMM uuuu` (a non ISO format) but you are trying to parse it with a `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`
2. Your datetime `String` is of the format `MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm:ss a` (non ISO) but you are trying to parse it with a `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`, which is at least doubly wrong because that formatter tries to parse an ISO date. Your `String` is non ISO and contains more information (time of day) than this formatter is able to parse.

There are several built-in `DateTimeFormatter`s, like the one you are currently using, but you need to use a correct one or if there is none, create one that covers your `String`(s) yourself (either by `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(...)` or by using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`).

Here's a small example for your `String` examples:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // your example Strings
    val dateFirst = "20 Aug 2012"
    val dateSecond = "12/16/2020 12:00:00 AM"
    // you need two different formatters here, your Strings differ in format and content
    val firstFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val secondFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH)
    // then use those according to what you want to parse
    val localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateFirst, firstFormatter)
    val localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateSecond, secondFormatter)
    // use the built-in formatters for output
    println(localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE))
    println(localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME))
}
```

Output (in ISO):

```
2012-08-20
2020-12-16T00:00:00
```